# How to pass member function as an argument and use it in curl callback

Tags: c++, libcurl

I have two files - handler.cpp and client.cpp

In handler.cpp,   I have written a code to handle response received from rest APIs and in client.cpp I have interfaces to run those rest apis.

handler.cpp =>

```
#include <client.h>

struct EventHandlerInfo
{
    string partialEvent;
};

class Handler
{
    size_t HandleEvent( void* userData, size_t size, size_t nmemb, EventHandlerInfo* eventHandlerInfo );
    bool MakeRequest();
};

size_t Handler::HandleEvent( void* userData, size_t size, size_t nmemb, EventHandlerInfo*    eventHandlerInfo )
{
    // impl to process rest api response
}

bool MakeRequest()
{
    Client client;
    .....
    client.GETRequest( headers, errMsg );
    .....
    return true;
}
```

client.h =>

```
class Client
{
    bool GETRequest( vector<string> headers, string& errMsg );
};
```

client.cpp =>

```
bool Client::GETRequest( vector<string> headers, string& errMsg )
{
    // impl

    curl_easy_setopt( m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, **func** );
    curl_easy_setopt( m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, **(void*) eventHandlerInfo** );

    // curl perform
   
    return true;
}
```

I want to use HandleEvent function from handler.cpp as a callback in curl_easy_setopt() in place of 'func'. I have tried passing HanbdleEvent function as an argument to GETRequest function. In client.cpp I received it using std::function<size_t(void*,size_t,size_t,EventHandlerInfo*)> It did compile successfully. But when I ran binary I got seg fault whenever curl tried to use it.

Can anyone pl help me with this?
Thanks in advance!

I am open for all suggestions.

Comment: Normally not going to work, A member function will always have an implicit first parameter (this), which will not be inserted by the callback made by the library. It seems however you can pass user data and you can inject a pointer to your object instance : more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974371/libcurl-callbacks-w-c-class-members

Comment: Member function pointers are not actually pointers. Also see [How can I pass a member function where a free function is expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662891/how-can-i-pass-a-member-function-where-a-free-function-is-expected) and [Passing a pointer to a class member function as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145874/passing-a-pointer-to-a-class-member-function-as-a-parameter).